# Телеграм бот inlinekeyboardbutton надпись ограничение на количество символов

Tags: telegram-bot

пишется бот Телеграм на C# ,  использую библиотеку Telegram.Bot.15.7.1
Подскажите пожалуйста, существует ли ограничение на количество символов в заголовке инлайн кнопки?
Перенос строки не помогает, текст разделяется на 2 строки, но количество символов остается тем же.Если все таки существует ограничение, можете указать пруф?

Answer (score 1):

Нет какого-то жёсткого лимита длины надписей на inline-кнопках. Если текст всё таки слишком длинный, то он будет обрезаться клиентом. В каком месте произойдёт усечение, зависит от ширины экрана устройства или окна программы. И ещё, обратите внимание, если текст обрезается, на компьютере его всё равно можно увидеть полностью — во всплывающей подсказке при наведении указателя мыши.

[image: пример такой всплывающей подсказке]

Comment: в том то и дело, что надо именно в клиенте смартфона смотреть, в десктопном клиенте все нормально... А в андроид - клиенте вроде и перенос строки работает , но текст обрезается.